# Adding a user to a specific GAL in a multitenant exchange environment

Tags: exchange-server, exchange-server-2013

I have a multi-tenant exchange 2013 environment which is used by several customers.

We recently added a new user to one of our customers domains via the EAC.

The correct habitat was selected etc, but this user was not added to the GAL of that customer.
I am unable to add them via EAC as I get the message...

> *This global address list was created using the Exchange Management*
>   *Shell. Please use the Shell to modify it.*

I have had a search through google and cannot seem to find the command to simply add an existing user to the GAL.

Is anyone able to tell me what command I would need to use here?

Many thanks in advance for assistance, I've already spent several hours trying unsuccessfully to get this user into the GAL and really need to get this issue closed off.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a recipient filter to organize your GALs and ABPs?  If so, I would verify the user has the filter for the GAL and then run Update-AddressList "Name of GAL" and see if the user gets added.

You can manually edit the showInAddressBook attribute and add the dn of the GAL but I'd try and figure out why the user isn't in the proper GAL first.